# Почему в некоторых именах (Екатерина, Елизавета) часто отбрасывается  первая буква Е?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, ономастика

-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просторечно-разговорные варианты.
Они вполне в духе русского языка. А то многовато слогов получается - да ещё с не совсем типичной для русского гласной в начале.

Answer (score 1):

А в некоторых именах (например,Евдокия и Елена) Е заменили на привычное русскому уху А. Получились Авдотья и Алёна.

Answer (score -1):

К сведению.

Евдокия - это Дуся.
А Авдотья - это Дуня.

Comment: Дуня  и  Дуся  -  одно  и  тоже.

Comment: Не могу согласиться. Дайте, плиз, соответствующую ссылку.

Comment: Пожалуйста: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?pe=x&word=%E5%E2%E4%EE%EA%E8%FF


>>**ЕВДОКИЯ**, -и, ж.; народн. **Авдотья**, -и; прост. Авдокея, -и и Евдокея, -и.
Производные: Евдокиюшка; Евдя; Евдоня; Доня (Дона); Доняха; Доняша; Евдося; Дося; Евдоха; Евдоша; Доша; Евдуня; **Дуня**; Дуняра; Дунятка; Дуняха; Дуняша; Евдуша; Душа.
Авдотьюшка; Авдотька; Авдоня; Авдоха; Авдоша; Авдуля; Авдуся; **Дуся**.
    [Греч. eudokia — благоволение.]
    †14 марта, 30 мая, 20 июля, 17 авг., 26 авг.

Словарь русских имён (Петровский).